Is the cartesian product of arbitrary family of open sets still open in product topology?
There's plenty of material out there about the finite case, but I'm not sure how to approach the general case. In the box topology the statement is true and it follows directly from the defintion, but what about this tychonoff topology?
Here's the definition from ProofWiki:
Let $\{(X_i,\tau_i)\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces where $\mathcal{I}$ is an arbitrary index set.
The product topology,$\tau$, on $\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ is defined as the topology generated by
$$\mathcal{S}=\{\pi_i^{-1}(U);\ i\in\mathcal{I},U\in\tau_i\}.$$
If the statement turns out to be false, can anyone provide a counterexample?

The answer is No, otherwise ${0,1}^{\omega}$ would be discrete, but it's not. You cannot write the set ${(0,0,\dotsc)}$ as a union of finite intersections of sets of the form $p_i^{-1}(0)$.
